# able to run the code of C with MakeFile, but nut able to debug it with Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I want to debug my code in c, but I get error. I not sure why I have the error, because i able to run it. I will explain: i have following files: `file1.c ,file1.h ,file2.c , file2.c, main.c`. I use makefile to create obj file and to run the code. For the debug i also create launch.json with (gdb).

makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -O2
LDFLAGS = -lcrypto
OBJFILES = file1.o file1.o main.o
TARGET = main

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJFILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJFILES) $(LDFLAGS)
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJFILES) $(TARGET) *~
```

launch.json

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

the run the code i run following commends, and its working.

```
make clean
make
./main
```

for the debug I trying this commend, but its not working:

```
gcc -g file1.c file2.c main.c main -lcrypto
```

But I got an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: main: stdout: invalid version 4 (max 0)
/usr/bin/ld: main: error adding symbols: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What I trying to do, and what I expect:

I also try different commend

```
gcc -g * -lcrypto
```

now i got the same error, and also file1.h.gch, file2.h.gch was created. I'm new with makefiles, I not sure why i can run the code but not debug it. I want to debug my code, not sure what i missing.

Comment: `gcc -g file1.c file2.c main.c main -lcrypto` -> `gcc -g file1.c file2.c main.c -o main -lcrypto`

Comment: cool thanks! i forget -o

Comment: You can eliminate the line "    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJFILES) $(LDFLAGS)" and just use the builtin catalog rule for building binaries.  Set `LDLIBS := -lcrypt` instead of LDFLAGS.  You should add `.PHONY: all clean`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you use for gcc is not correct.  It should be:

```
gcc -g file1.c file2.c main.c -o main -lcrypto
```

Or you use your existing Makefile and just override the CFLAGS variable:

```
make clean
make CFLAGS=-g
```